# Use PHP for Cross Site Loading of HTML Content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, simple-html-dom

Maybe a stupid question, but I'm wrecked from this issue.

The issue: cross domain loading of webpage via javascript and having access to variables and elements within

Theoretical solution:

1. Send an ajax request to a local php file with the requested URL as a parameter
2. Get the PHP file to load the page
3. Display the loaded page and have access to the elements in a box specified

Before I endeavor, is something like this possible or worth the work involved? I am familar with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Thanks in advance, have spent quite some time on this issue already.

---

## Update

First, the javascript:

```
function loadTheUrl(x){      // x = the url, e.g. http://example.com
    $.ajax({ url: 'loader.php', // explained below
         data: {url: x},
         type: 'get',
         success: function(output) {
                      $('.loading-space').html(output);
                  }
            });
         
  }
```

This calls a local PHP file called loader.php

#### loader.php

```
<?php

    echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
```

And that's it. This works, but it actually gives me some issues with CSS that I am trying to figure out. The CSS is overriding my site too.. I'd like to keep the CSS, but limit it to within that div.

---

## Update

A semi-working example. Only works in Chrome due to data:text/html.

### HTML

```
<div value='http://example.com' onClick='javascript:loadURL(this)'>Click Here</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
function loadURL(x){
    var xURL = $(x).attr('value');
    $.ajax({ url: 'load.php',
         data: {url: xURL},
         type: 'get',
         success: function(output) {
                $('.page-loaded').attr("data", "data:text/html,"+output); // .page-loaded is an HTML object element
                  }
            });
  }
```

### load.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($_GET['url']));
    echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Just curious as to why the downvotes are coming in. I would have thought this issue would have been more widespread? Thanks

---

#### Update

PHP way doesn't allow to access elements. CORS seems the only way to go. Just need to limit CSS to within the box.

Comment: is the other domain another that you control, or is it controlled by someone else?

Comment: I don't have control of the other site, but they are using a solution I've provided. I am just trying to replicate the site without the ordinary callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking to do?

```
   <script>
    $(function(){
      $.get("youFile.php", function(data){
          $("#container").html(data);
      });
    }):
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes but it's cross domain, so I don't have access to the elements/variables. Trying for a work around. All I want is to display the page really, and ensure no onbeforeunloads are initiated.

Comment: If it's cross domain, I don't think there is going to be a solution.

Comment: Using a local PHP file I think it can be done, I've got the page contents into the div, but the CSS included is causing issues with my site.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle of what you are trying to do? I'm a little confused, cross site scripting and manipulating a local php file are a little different in my opinion.

Comment: can't fiddle with php file loading the actual URL but have updated the above with the three files that work together

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DOMDocument`, find all the `script` and `link` tags, remove them, and spit out the HTML:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($_GET['url']));
$internal_css = $doc->getElementsByTagName('style');
foreach ($internal_css as $css) {
    $css->nodeValue = "#container_id " . implode(" #container_id ", explode("}", $css->nodeValue));
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: clever solution; but what I'm trying to keep the CSS but limit it to just within the div I'm displaying the file in - if that's possible?

Comment: This edit shows how to do it for anything inside a `<style>` tag... for the external resources, you'd have to set the href attribute to a page you control, `file_get_contents` the url, do the `implode` `explode` on the contents, and then return it.

Comment: Thanks @dave, appreciate it but it's still not working as intended. I wonder can I create the DOM element and pass it as a 'file' via `DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile` and initiate an object element with that 'file' as the data? Or something along those lines.. Thanks anyways!